# How do I create a floating window using onClick attribute in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

So I'm working on an Android app (in Eclipse) and I've hit a wall.  In my app I have a drawer that slides out with a list of options.  I would like the user to be able to click one of the options and to bring up a floating window with a form in it.  I'm trying to do this using the onClick attribute on the buttons rather than using a onClickListener. Is this possible without having to use a onClickListener or am I trying to avoid the inevitable?  The button's onClick attribute in my layout has a value of "newWindow".

My MainActivity class

```
public void newWindow(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
        = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
       View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                  popupView, 
                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 

    };
    startActivity(intent);

    }
```

I see my popupView variable is unused but I'm not sure where to place or if I'm even headed in the right direction.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The simplest option I can think of is a 'Dialog'. Whether for user's input or to notify that will do the trick. Then move on to fragments. Starting an activity like this doesn't look pretty though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't for the life of me figure out why you are trying to start an Activity with an Intent here. Your code shold be:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popupWindow.showAtLocation(...); // or showAsDropdown(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm completely green when it comes to Android Development.  I was just mimicking.  I don't have a complete understanding on how Intents work as of yet.